# Avoid Adding Repeat Object to Realm

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, realm

I query down the data from Parse.com and save them in the local Realm database (iOS/swift). Each object has a unique property(A) but also a might-be-same property(B). What is the most efficient way to avoid adding objects with same property B into the realm database? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can set a primary key on an object so that Realm guarantees that there is only one of each object in the DB.

```
class Person: RLMObject {
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var name = ""

    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

You will still need to do a check yourself whether that object is in the DB already or not. It would fetch the object based on the primary key (either looking for objects via property(A) or property(B)). Then if the object exists, don't add, if it doesn't exist, add it to the DB.

Something like this:

```
var personThatExists = Person.objectsWhere("id == %@", primaryKeyValueHere).firstObject()

  if personThatExists { 
    //don't add 
  } else { 
    //add our object to the DB 
  }
```

If you use primary keys and you don't care about the object's values being updated, you can use the [createOrUpdate](http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.90.6/api/Classes/RLMObject.html#//api/name/createOrUpdateInDefaultRealmWithObject:) method. Realm will create a new object if one doesn't exist, otherwise it will update the one that exists with the values from the object you pass in.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. So every time I add a new object to realm, I set the id equal to the propertyB (string) which I pull down from Parse. If the new object's id equal to one of the existing object id, does realm gives back error or just ignore the adding. If it gives back error, how to handle the callback to skip adding? (I haven't find addObject function in realm has callback block)

Comment: It will error, not allowing you to do it. Correct there isn't a callback block. You would need to create your own method that does the check before adding. I added an example to the code above.

An easier way to do this could be to use createOrUpdate since you have a primary key. Realm will then create a new object if it doesn't exist, or update the existing one with the object you pass in so you don't need to do a check at all

Comment: http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.90.6/api/Classes/RLMObject.html#//api/name/createOrUpdateInDefaultRealmWithObject:

Comment: Glad to hear! Gl with the project